# Problems inserting a new entry in Astra Cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax-astra

I am doing a migration from Cassandra on an AWS machine to Astra Cassandra and there are some problems :

I cannot insert new data in Astra Cassandra with a column which is around 2 million characters and 1.77 MB (and I have bigger data to insert - around 20 millions characters). Any one knows how to address the problem?

I am inserting it via a Python app (cassandra-driver==3.17.0) and this is the error stack I get :

```
start.sh[5625]: [2022-07-12 15:14:39,336] 
INFO in db_ops: error = Error from server: code=1500
[Replica(s) failed to execute write] 
message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 2 failures: UNKNOWN from 0.0.0.125:7000, UNKNOWN from 0.0.0.181:7000" 
info={'consistency': 'LOCAL_QUORUM', 'required_responses': 2, 'received_responses': 0, 'failures': 2}
```

If I used half of those characters it works.

new Astra Cassandra CQL Console table description :

```
token@cqlsh> describe mykeyspace.series;

CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.series (
    type text,
    name text,
    as_of timestamp,
    data text,
    hash text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((type, name, as_of))
) WITH additional_write_policy = '99PERCENTILE'
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.UnifiedCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair = 'BLOCKING'
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Old Cassandra table description:

```
ansible@cqlsh> describe mykeyspace.series;

CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.series (
    type text,
    name text,
    as_of timestamp,
    data text,
    hash text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((type, name, as_of))
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Data sample :

```
{"type": "OP", "name": "book", "as_of": "2022-03-17", "data": [{"year": 2022, "month": 3, "day": 17, "hour": 0, "quarter": 1, "week": 11, "wk_year": 2022, "is_peak": 0, "value": 1.28056854009628e-08}, .... ], "hash": "84421b8d934b06488e1ac464bd46e83ccd2beea5eb2f9f2c52428b706a9b2a10"}

where this json contains 27.000 entries inside the data array like : 

{"year": 2022, "month": 3, "day": 17, "hour": 0, "quarter": 1, "week": 11, "wk_year": 2022, "is_peak": 0, "value": 1.28056854009628e-08}
```

Python part of the code :

```
def insert_to_table(self, table_name, **kwargs):
        try:
            ...
            elif table_name == "series":
                self.session.execute(
                    self.session.prepare("INSERT INTO series (type, name, as_of, data, hash) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"),
                    (
                        kwargs["type"],
                        kwargs["name"],
                        kwargs["as_of"],
                        kwargs["data"],
                        kwargs["hash"],
                    ),
                )
            return True
        except Exception as error:
            current_app.logger.error('src/db/db_ops.py insert_to_table() table_name = %s error = %s', table_name, error)
            return False
```

Big thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the short solution to make a data migration possible for an inhouse Cassandra DB to Astra Cassandra (DataStax) was to use compression (zlib).

So the "data" field of each entry was compress in Python with zlib and then stored in Cassandra to reduce the size of the entries.

```
    def insert_to_table(self, table_name, **kwargs):
        try:
            if table_name == 'series_as_of':
                ...
            elif table_name == 'series':
                list_of_bytes = bytes(json.dumps(kwargs["data"]),'latin1')
                compressed_data = zlib.compress(list_of_bytes)
                a = str(compressed_data, 'latin1')

                self.session.execute(
                    self.session.prepare(INSERT_SERIES_QUERY),
                        (
                            kwargs["type"],
                            kwargs["name"],
                            kwargs["as_of"],
                            a,
                            kwargs["hash"],
                        ),
                    )
    ....
```

Then, when reading the entries, a decompression step is needed :

```
    def get_series(self, query_type, **kwargs):
        try:
            if query_type == "data":
                execution = self.session.execute_async(
                    self.session.prepare(GET_SERIES_DATA_QUERY),
                    (kwargs["type"], kwargs["name"], kwargs["as_of"]),
                    timeout=30,
                )
                decompressed = None
                a = None
                for row in execution.result():
                    my_bytes = row[0].encode('latin1')
                    decompressed = zlib.decompress(my_bytes)
                    a = str(decompressed, encoding="latin1")
                return a
    ...
```

The data looks like this now in Astra Cassandra :

```
token@cqlsh> select * from series where type = 'OP' and name = 'ZTP_PFM_H_LUX_PHY' and as_of = '2022-09-30';

 type | name              | as_of                           | data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | hash
------+-------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
   OP | ZTP_PFM_H_LUX_PHY | 2022-09-30 00:00:00.000000+0000 | x\x9c-\x8dÉ\nÂ@\x10D\x7fEúl`z\x16Mü\x80\x90\x83â\x1c\x14\F\x86îYÈÅ\x05\x92\x8b\x88ÿnÂx*ªÞ\x83\x82\x8f\x83ñýJ\x0e6\x0b\x07{ë`9å\x83îÿår°Þ¶;ßùíñämw.\x02\rþ\x99\x8b!\x85\x94\x95h*%\n\x8a4ÒL®·¹õ4ôÅÓÙ¨\x10\të \x99H\x04¡\x8cf6¹!\x95\x02'\x93"Jb\x1dë\x84ÈT¯U\x90\x19\x11W8\x1dp£\x8d\x83/ü\x00Ó<0\x99 | 4f53cda18c2baa0c0354bb5f9a3ecbe5ed12ab4d8e11ba873c2f11161202b945

(1 rows)
```

Long term solution is to rearrange the data like @Stefano Lottini said.

Answer (score 1):

you are hitting the configured limit for the maximum mutation size. On Cassandra, this defaults to 16 MB, while on Astra DB at the moment it is 4 MB (it's possible that it will be raised, but performing inserts with veyr large cell sizes is still strongly discouraged).

A more agile approach to storing this data would be to revise your data model and split the big row with the huge string into several rows, each containing a single item of the 27000 or so entries. With proper use of partitioning, you would still be able to retrieve the whole contents with a single query (paginated between the database and the driver for your convenience, which would help avoiding annoying timeouts which may arise when reading so large individual rows).

Incidentally, I suggest you create the prepared statement only once outside of the `insert_to_table` function (caching it or something). In the insert function you simply `self.session.execute(already_prepared_statement, (value1, value2, ...))` which would noticeably improve your performance.

A last point: I believe the drivers are able to connect to Astra DB only starting from version 3.24.0, so I'm not sure how you are using version 3.17. I don't think version 3.17 know of the `cloud` argument to the `Cluster` constructor. In any case, I suggest you upgrade the drivers to the latest version (currently 3.25.0).

Answer (score 0):

There's something not quite right with the details you posted in your question.

In the schema you posted, the `data` column is of type `text`:

```
    data text,
```

But the sample data you posted looks like you are inserting key/value pairs which oddly seems to be formatted like a CQL collection type.

If it were really a string, it would be formatted as:

```
    ... "data": "key1: value1, key2: value2, ...", ...
```

Review your data and code then try again. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It works with the in house Cassandra, I just insert an array of json dicts. Maybe the structure define for storing my data in Cassandra is strange, but this does not address this problem of why it works with the same data in one and not in the other with the same code. I guess it's either a character limit problem or it's a configuration of the table when created.